# Programmatically expand my image in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

I've got an image made of a number of slowly expanding arcs. Now I want to add another 10 wedges, over the same total angle (so each arc will be ~14º).

I'm trying to use the following code, but I'm getting the error below.

How can I use `\pgfmathprintnumber` in `\draw arc`, or alternatively, what's a better approach to generating my arcs in a short loop?

```
\foreach \i in {0,...,10} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\result{\i * -14};
    \draw ++(6:\i) arc (6:{\pgfmathprintnumber{\result}}:\i);
}


! Use of \tikz@@arcto doesn't match its definition.
```

[image: My current image]

Here's my current MWE (code for current image, plus attempt to expand using `foreach`):

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [gray!50] ++(25:1) arc (25:-205:1);
\draw [gray!50] ++(25:2) arc (25:-205:2);
\draw [gray!50] ++(25:3) arc (25:-205:3);
\draw [gray!50] ++(25:4) arc (25:-205:4);

\node [anchor=south] at (25:1) {W1};
\node [anchor=south] at (25:2) {W2};
\node [anchor=south] at (25:3) {W3};
\node [anchor=south] at (25:4) {W4};

\foreach \i in {0,...,10} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\result{\i * -14};
    \draw ++(6:\i) arc (6:{\pgfmathprintnumber{\result}}:\i);
}

\draw (0,0) -- (6:4);
\draw ++(6:1) arc (6:-15:1);
\draw (0,0) -- (-15:1);
\draw ++(6:2) arc (6:-45:2);
\draw (0,0) -- (-45:2);
\draw ++(6:3) arc (6:-90:3);
\draw (0,0) -- (-90:3);
\draw ++(6:4) arc (6:-140:4);
\draw (0,0) -- (-140:4);

\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\pgfmathprintnumber` gives the printable result ("text"). It is not a number.

Comment: As @Astrinus suggested just use `\draw ++(6:\i) arc (6:\result:\i);` (i.e., elimniate the `\pgfmathprintnumber`).  Also, I would suggest you use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` instead of `\pgfmathsetmacro` to avoid any potential issues with floating point round off.

Comment: Not sure exactly what the desired result is, but if you want the ends of the arcs to be connected to the origin you'll want `\draw (0,0) -- ++(6:\i) arc (6:\result:\i) -- (0,0);`.

Comment: @Astrinus Thank you. Can't believe I overlooked that.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks for the code, and the `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` hint. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what do you mean by *total angle*. But It should be easy to modify the code.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round]
        \foreach\i/\result in{1/-15,2/-45,3/-90,4/-140}{
            \draw[gray!50](25:\i)node[above,black]{$W_{\i}$}arc(25:-205:\i);
            \draw(6:\i-1)--(6:\i)arc(6:\result:\i)--(0,0);
        }
        \foreach\i in{1,...,10}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro\result{-14.6*\i+6};
            \draw[gray!50](25:\i+4)arc(25:-205:\i+4);
            \draw(6:\i+3)--(6:\i+4)arc(6:\result:\i+4)--(\result:4);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sure this much OP already has it. See the comments.

Comment: @percusse I saw OP saying thankyou to everyone but I am not sure if OP finished his job. By the way there is a problem in comments. For instance `\draw(0,0)--++(6:\i)arc(6:\result:\i)--(0,0);` is worse than `\draw(0,0)--(6:\i)arc(6:\result:\i)--cycle;`, but both make some lines too thick for some renderer.